# DialogReturn evaluated too soon

Tags: hold, dialog-window

Why does this module return 11 (as expected) when 'Accept' is clicked:

```
blist = {{"Accept", 11}, {"Cancel", $Failed}};
thisWorks[] := Module[{buttons = {}},
   Map[AppendTo[buttons, Button[#[[1]], DialogReturn[#[[2]]]]]&, blist];
   Return@DialogInput[buttons, Modal->True]
  ];
```

while this module does not?

```
thisFails[] := Module[{i, n, buttons = {}},
   For[i = 1; n = Length@blist, i <= n, i++,
    AppendTo[buttons,
     Button[blist[[i, 1]], DialogReturn[blist[[i, 2]]]]]]; 
   Return@DialogInput[buttons, Modal->True]
  ];
```

Hold@DialogReturn does not work either, in fact, thisFails[] does not return if used.

(Not that anyone would EVER want to use a For loop, of course :)

Comment: Take a look at `InputForm @ buttons` instead of `DialogInput`. `For/Do/Table` are not able to inject values of iterators into held expressions, and `Button` is `HoldRest`. p.s. `Return` is redundant.

Comment: Linked topic should answer your doubts, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: I don't really understand the linked example, but agree that it seems to be asking a related question.  Just to put my mind at rest -- there is no way to use a For loop here?  If there is a way, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: The linked question is different but check the answer. You can use For, add mentioned trick in for's body: With[{i=i...

Comment: P.s use Table instead of for +  append

Comment: OK Kuba, thanks.  With[{k = i}... works.
Go ahead and kill it if you like.

Comment: No, marking as duplicate has a purpose of leaving a road sign for future visitors.